# Does Haskell "understand" curried function definitions?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell functions always take one parameter. Multiple parameters are implemented via [Currying](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html). That being the case, I can see how a function of two parameters would be defined as "func1" below. It's a function that returns a function (closure) that adds the outer function's single parameter to the returned function's single parameter.

However, although this is how curried functions *work*, that's not the regular Haskell syntax for defining a two-parameter function. Instead we're taught to define such a function like "func2".

I'd like to know how Haskell understands that func2 should behave the same way as func1. There's nothing about the definition of func2 that suggest to me that it is a function that returns a function. To the contrary it actually looks like a two-parameter function, something we're told doesn't exist!

What's the trick here? Is Haskell just born knowing that we can define multi-parameter functions in this textbook way, and that they work the way we expect anyhow? That is, is this a syntax convention that doesn't seem to be clearly documented (Haskell knows what you mean and will supply the missing function return for you), or is there some other magic at work or something I'm missing?

```
func1 :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
func1 x = (\y -> x + y)

func2 :: Int -> Int -> Int
func2 x y = x + y

main = do
    print (func1 7 9)
    print (func2 7 9)
```

Comment: Haskell translates `func2` into `func1`.

Answer (score 7):

In the *language* itself, writing a function definition of the form `f x y z = _` is equivalent to `f = \x y z -> _`, which is equivalent to `f = \x -> \y -> \z -> _`. There's no theoretical reason for this; it's just that those nested lambda abstractions are a terrible eye-/finger-sore and everyone thought that it would be fine to sacrifice a bit of pedantry to make some syntax sugar for it. That's all there is on the surface and is probably all you need to know, for now.

In the *implementation* of the language, though, things get trickier. In GHC, which is the most common implementation, there actually is a difference between `f x y = _` and `f = \x -> \y -> _`. When GHC compiles Haskell, it assigns *arity* to declarations. The former definition of `f` has arity `2`, and the latter has arity `0`. Take `(.)` from `GHC.Base`

```
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x)
```

`(.)` has arity `2`, even though its type (`(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`) says that it can be applied up to thrice. This affects optimization: GHC will only inline a function that is *saturated*, or has at least as many arguments applied as its arity. In the call `(maximum .)`, `(.)` will not inline, because it only has one argument (it is *unsaturated*). In the call `(maximum . f)`, it *will* inline to `\x -> maximum (f x)`, and in `(maximum . f) 1`, the `(.)` will inline first to a lambda abstraction (producing `(\x -> maximum (f x)) 1`), which will beta-reduce to `maximum (f 1)`. If `(.)` were implemented

```
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

`(.)` would have arity `3`, which means it would inline less often (specifically the `f . g` case, which is a very common argument to higher order functions), likely reducing performance, which is exactly what the comment on it says:

> Make sure it has TWO args only on the left, so that it inlines
> when applied to two functions, even if there is no final argument

Final answer: the two forms *should be* equivalent, according to the language's semantics, but in GHC the two forms have different characteristics when it comes to optimization, even if they always give the same result.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. fwiw I think I figured out why this doesn't appear clearly in the literature: functions are typically introduced before lambda expressions but you can't explain this syntax sugar without first understanding the latter. I eventually found it explained in "Programming in Haskell" section 4.5 "Lambda expressions", pages after Curried Functions are discussed in section 3.6. The Tutorial page https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html is silent on the subject even though it introduces lambdas right there and talks about a function having two arguments..

Comment: The Haskell definition document is good at answering these kind of questions.

Answer (score 4):

When talking about type signatures, there is no such thing as a "multi-parameter function". All functions are single-parameter, period. Haskell doesn't need to somehow "translate" multi-parameter functions into single-parameter ones, because the former doesn't exist at all.

All function type signatures look like `a -> b`, where `a` is argument type and `b` is return type. Sometimes `b` may just happen to contain more arrows `->`, in which case we, humans (but not the compiler), may say that the function has multiple parameters.

When talking about the syntax for implementations, i.e. `f x y = z` - that is merely syntactic sugar, which gets desugared (i.e. mechanically transformed) into `f = \x -> \y -> z` during compilation.

Comment: Well, multi-parameter functions surely exist as a concept in the mind of whoever implemented said de-sugaring. Do you have a citation in the documentation where this de-sugaring is explained? I missed it in all the books and wiki pages I read, although clearly something like that had to be going on (hence my question). btw when I use the word "translate" that you say isn't happening, I actually mean the thing you say is happening, which you call "desugaring".

Comment: Realized it wasn't me who used the word "translate", although I easily could have. Desugaring is just a form of syntactic translation, no?

Comment: You cited two different type signatures and two different body definitions in your question, and asked how Haskell "knows" them to be equivalent. I answered for both: the first part of my answer is about type signatures, the second part is about body definitions.